# what is the Maximum number of concurrent users can browse in Magento 2 during

Tags: magento2, performance, server-setup

In a flash sale, what is the Maximum number of concurrent users that can browse in a Magento 2 instance

Answer (score 2):

The number of concurrent users your site can sustain totally depends on your specific server infrastructure and codebase. There is no single number for Magento in general.

If you want to learn your server's traffic capacity, you should do performance testing to determine it.

You may find that these tools help you do so:

- Magento Performance Toolkit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2/setup/performance-toolkit
- Siege: https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/
- JMeter: http://jmeter.apache.org/

You may find it helpful to run these tests in conjunction with a server metrics tool like New Relic for additional data on server throughput, response times, and resource load through the tests.